# Cached index.html content is wrapped in <pre>

Tags: html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

maybe I didn't understand how this is supposed to work. But I followed the Google Guides for PWA on Desktop and can install the PWA fine.
The only problem I have and couldn't find an answer for is, that the cached index.html is shown in plain text instead of rendered HTML.

My ServiceWorker looks like this:

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'backfuel-cache-v1';
const urlsToCache = [
    '/backfuel/src/manifest.json',
    '/backfuel/src/index.html',
    '/backfuel/src/css/Main.css',
    '/backfuel/src/app/Main.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    // Perform install steps
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function (cache) {
                console.log('Opened cache');
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Cache response: ', response.clone());
                // Cache hit - return response
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }

                return fetch(event.request).then(
                    function (response) {
                        // Check if we received a valid response
                        if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                            return response;
                        }

                        // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                        // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                        // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                        // to clone it so we have two streams.
                        const responseToCache = response.clone();

                        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                            .then(function (cache) {
                                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache).then(
                                    res => {
                                        console.log('Chached', res);
                                    },
                                    rej => {
                                        console.log('Cache Error: ', rej);
                                    });
                            });

                        return response;
                    }
                );
            })
    );
});
```

And the HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#eeeeee">
    <title>backfuel</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Karla|Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/backfuel/src/css/Main.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/backfuel/src/manifest.json">
    <script type="module" src="/backfuel/src/app/Main.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="title-bar">
            <h2 id="title">
                backfuel
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <ul class="carousel">
                <li class="carousel-item"><p>01.01.2020</p><p>32l</p><p>670km</p><p>44.26 &euro;</p></li>
                <li class="carousel-item"><p>20.01.2020</p><p>16l</p><p>250km</p><p>22.15 &euro;</p></li>
                <li class="carousel-item"><p>15.02.2020</p><p>64l</p><p>1001km</p><p>83.67 &euro;</p></li>
                <li class="carousel-item"><p>30.02.2020</p><p>8l</p><p>50km</p><p>5.81 &euro;</p></li>
                <li class="carousel-item"><p>10.03.2020</p><p>48l</p><p>750km</p><p>72.69 &euro;</p></li>
                <li class="carousel-item"><p>01.04.2020</p><p>56l</p><p>900km</p><p>85.18 &euro;</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="fab">
            +
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's the manifest:

```
{
  "short_name": "backfuel",
  "name": "backfuel",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "app/img/icons-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "app/img/icons-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/backfuel/src/",
  "background_color": "#eeeeee",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/backfuel/src/",
  "theme_color": "#ff0000"
}
```

The page displays the content of index.html as plain text when loaded from the ServiceWorker/Cache.
I'm sure this has to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find the right search to find an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like you are doing a single page app that is injecting the response in a PRE tag. 
FYI, this is not going to give you the HTML - console.log('Cache response: ', response.clone());
You need to do response.text() to get that.

Comment: If it were the behaviour i want  The real problem is, that it doesn't parse the html. It just displays it as text

Comment: I am confused by your reply.
The service worker doesn't alter the response body, well unless you write code to do that, and you have not done that.
How about this. Make a website with just static web pages. Add your service worker to that site. I think you will see the cached assets working the way you want.

Comment: I'm confused as well. Hence why i posted the question. Thank you for trying. Weirdly, on another computer, the Cache doesn't work at all.